# The use of "High-order" vs "Higher-order" to describe the order of accuracy of numerical schemes

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology, math-history

I would like to know if there is a qualitative difference between the phrases "high-order" and "higher-order". I have recently received a response to an article I submitted in the field of numerical methods for curvature computation of liquid-gas interfaces. In the article, I develop an arbitrary-order polynomial fitting procedure to reconstruct the liquid-gas interface, after which the interface curvature is computed (for surface tension computation purposes). I titled the article "A Higher-order Accurate ..." because I manage to demonstrate that the "order of accuracy" of the procedure matches the order of the fitted polynomial.

One of the reviewers of the article strongly suggests replacing "higher-order" with "high-order". I partially understand this request as I have noticed a trend where a number of researchers in my field use the phrase "high-order" in similar contexts to mine (although most still use "higher-order"). However, I gravitate towards "higher-order" as it is widely used all over mathematics. Can anyone advise me on the differences (if any) between these two phrases, and which one I should adopt?

Comment: I have NEVER seen "Higher Order" used in a math paper!

Comment: For me, if I read *higher* I expect to read *than* just after

Comment: @user247327 See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/42387089_On_Ostrowski-Type_Inequalities_for_Higher-Order_Partial_Derivatives , https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming/article/higher-order-functions-and-brouwers-thesis/938CB9864C34CA33A41F8202620918A3 ,

Comment: @user247327 There's no shortage of examples of math articles with "Higher order"

Comment: In the end, it is a matter of style. Higher order is acceptable if it is quite clear what the usual order is in problems of that type. If you think of it, High order is just as bad in the sense that it also requires some opinion on what is high or not... Is three high? is four high?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I agree with that argument. Regardless, "higher order" is used in the context of derivatives, PDEs, etc. right?

Comment: I honestly prefer "higher order" as it does not require a definition of what is to be considered high, just a comparison to what is common.

Comment: An example from SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis 54(1): A Higher Order Finite Element Method for Partial Differential Equations on Surfaces. 388-414.

Comment: @PierreCarre Thanks, I agree - it seems to be a very subjective matter. I just wish that there were more consistence in the phrase adopted. "High-order" is fairly recent compared to "Higher-order". I can't help but cringe when I see the former, for some reason, haha!

Comment: @niran90 You don't need to agree with the reviewer... Just say why you won't change it and give examples of high quality publications that use "higher" in the same context.

Comment: @PierreCarre Yes, that's what I had planned on doing :)

Comment: Not knowing the field, "a higher-order accurate..." makes me think "is this higher-order than some particular algorithm that you're improving upon/superceding?", whereas "high-order" wouldn't carry that possible reading.

Comment: @MarkS. Yes... but what is high? We are always comparing with some base level.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it difficult to settle language issues without face to face communication, something which is not possible here. It may be possible to avoid the issue entirely and still attract the right audience. Consider the title *"Methods of arbitrary order for approximating <something relevant>."* In the abstract, write something along the lines of : "Given an positive integer $p$ we show how to generate approximations of order $p$ for <something relevant>".

Comment: I agree with this in theory. However, in my specific field, it is considered conventional to refer to all numerical methods whose orders of convergence are greater than 2 as "higher-order" or (albeit less frequently) "high-order". Therefore, I'd prefer to not deviate from this convention.

Comment: @niran90 I think you can successfully argue that you are simply following the convention of your field. If necessary, examine the last few years of the journal and present the reviewer with a summary of your findings. This can upset the reviewer, so it is critical that you phrase it politely, i.e., you are not a native English speaker (if that is indeed that case) and you have therefore examined the recent literature to determine the norm.

Comment: @niran90. If we speak about *"numerical methods whose orders of convergence are greater than 2"*, we imply *"than Newton method"*

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Sure, but I don't see how that relates to "higher-order" vs "high-order"?